# Approximating a line integral over a rectifiable path by a line integral over a polygonal path in an infinite dimensional space

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $E$ be a complex Banach algebra and $U\subseteq E$ an open subset. Suppose we are given a continuous map $f:U\to E$ and a rectifiable path $\gamma:[a,b]\to U$.

> For each tagged partition $\{a=t_0<t_1<\dots<t_n=b\}$ with tags $\tau_k\in [t_{k-1},t_k]$, we consider the Riemann sum
> $$
> \sum_{k=1}^n f(\gamma(\tau_k))\mkern2mu[\gamma(t_k)-\gamma(t_{k-1})].
> $$
> Analagously to the case $E=\mathbb{C}$, we may define the line integral of $f$ along $\gamma$ by the limit of the net of Riemann sums as the mesh of the partitions tends to $0$. (This limit exists, since $f$ is continuous and $\gamma$ is rectifiable.)

I want to prove the following lemma from Conway's book on Complex Analysis (cf. page 65) in this more general setting.

> **1.19 Lemma.** For every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a polygonal path $\Gamma$ in $U$ such that $\Gamma(a)=\gamma(a)$, $\Gamma(b)=\gamma(b)$ and $$\Bigl\lvert\int_{\gamma} f-\int_{\Gamma}f\mkern2mu\Bigr\rvert<\epsilon.$$

By [this](https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlId=10.2969%2Fjmsj%2F01110076) old paper on Cauchy's theorem in Banach spaces, the above lemma is easily seen to be true (cf. page 77). On the other hand, an essential part of Conway's proof uses the fact that $\mathbb{C}$ is locally compact and hence $f$ uniformly continuous in a neighbourhood of $\gamma([a,b])$, which is not the case anymore if $E$ is infinite dimensional. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

The paper you cite does not show exactly this statement: it uses a stronger hypothesis than continuity on $f$ to gaurantee the argument works. One should expect non-uniform continuity to represent a real problem if only continuity is assumed. In the paper you linked, the function $f$ is required to have the analog of continuous differentiability that $$\delta(z,h) = \lim_{\lambda \to 0} \frac{f(z+\lambda h) - f(z)}{\lambda}$$ be continuous in a neighborhood of a point $z_0$ where it is "F-differenntiable." This implies that $f$ is locally Lipschitz, which is enough to give uniform continuity in a neighborhood of $\gamma$ and make the argument work as it does in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the paper, $f$ is said to be "G-differentiable" if the directional derivative $$\delta f(z,h)=\lim_{\lambda\to 0}\frac{f(z+\lambda h)-f(z)}{\lambda}$$ exists for all $z\in U$ and $h\in E$. If further $\delta f(z,h)$ is continuous in $h$, then $f$ is called "F-differentiable". They assume $f$ is "F-differentiable" such that $\delta f(z,h)k=\delta f(z,k)h$. This would be satisfied if we assume $f$ is (Fréchet) differentiable (in this case $\delta f (z,\cdot\,)=Df(z)$ holds) such that $[Df(z)h]k=[Df(z)k]h$. I don't see how this implies that $f$ is locally Lipschitz.